Parameter Count Mismatch using FluentEmail UseTemplateFromFile()
I have a .NET 7 project and I am trying to implement FluentEmail with Razor Templates so I can send emails to users for various different reasons. However I keep hitting Parameter count mismatch which i think is coming from .UseTemplateFromFile()
It is configured in Startup.cs as so
services.AddFluentEmail("noreply@rackemapp.com")
        .AddRazorRenderer()
        .AddSmtpSender(smtpsettings["Server"], Convert.ToInt32(smtpsettings["Port"]), smtpsettings["Username"], smtpsettings["Password"]);

And in the controller where I am trying to send my email, the code looks like this. The namespace of the project is RackEmApp and the view lives in /Views/EmailTemplates
var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                    var email = FluentEmail.Core.Email
                        .From("test@test.com")
                        .To(sendto)
                        .Subject(subject)
                        .UsingTemplateFromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Views/EmailTemplates/NewUserAdminNotification.cshtml", mergefields);


However, when I try and execute it, I get the response TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
